# Unable to patrol enemies

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just can’t figure out how to make random points for patrolling, I went through 100 manuals, but I can’t do it.
No need to write about NavMeshAgent. Not used.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
public sealed class Manikin : MonoBehaviour {

    private Vector3 StartManikin = Vector3.zero,
                    NewPosition = Vector3.zero;
    private readonly float Speed = 2.0f;

    void Start() {
        StartManikin = transform.position;
    }
    
    void Update() {
        if (Vector3.zero == NewPosition) {
            NewPosition = StartManikin + Random.onUnitSphere * 2;
        }
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, NewPosition) < 0.1f) {
            StartManikin = transform.position;
            NewPosition = Vector3.zero;
        } else {
            transform.LookAt(new Vector3(NewPosition.x, StartManikin.y, NewPosition.z));
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, NewPosition, Speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that there may be obstacles in the form of a fence, a tree, houses, cars, etc.

I need that when the enemy appears, random points are generated in his radius so that he does not leave further.
Help me out, I can’t figure out what needs to be done to make everything work ...

Comment: Why not add an OnCollisionEnter function and if collision.tag is obstacle then they rotate away

Comment: @Displayname, the problem was only moving to a random next position, not a collision, I added it as an addition to represent, if suddenly, someone would answer that there would not just be a straight line.

Comment: Then why not just generate a new random Vector3 within a certain range of the GameObject or create a set of transforms to wander towards?

Comment: @Displayname, that's how it works, it generates a random dot within the radius of the unit's sphere.

Comment: I don't see a problem then, you generate transforms to move to, you manipulate the position to move towards the position, you handle once the GameObject reaches the target.

What else are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Displayname, yes - yes, that's okay! I just didn't see it at first, that the model has a pivot below the Terrain and it just happens that the collider is pushed out or stuck, and then it takes off at super speeds =)))

Comment: If you get stuck on the floor then consider adding code to always have Vector3.y so far off the ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I just did not see that the Pivot of the model is not clear where, it flies in another dimension, the problem is solved, it is necessary to reset all transformations and the world point of the model's coordinates.

I didn’t see it right away, all the options turned out to be working ...

And also, it was necessary to fix the problem with the take-off along the y-axis, so that this does not happen, you need to look at the bottom point of the object from which we will spawn the coordinate for it.

```
if (Vector3.zero == NewPosition) {
    NewPosition = StartManikin + (Random.onUnitSphere * 5);
    NewPosition.y = transform.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>().bounds.min.y;
}
if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, NewPosition) < 0.1f) {
    StartManikin = transform.position;
    NewPosition = Vector3.zero;
} else {
   transform.LookAt(new Vector3(NewPosition.x, transform.position.y, NewPosition.z));
   transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, NewPosition, Speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```